# Launch Win 7 from Grub Terminal?

Tags: ubuntu, grub, gnu

I  tried to install Ubuntu via Win 7 from my SD card where I used a program to mount the is file. I launched the installer from Windows and I asked the program to reboot and it launched Ubuntu from SD card and all looked good viewing Ubuntu.   I connected to wifi,  pressed install,  It asked to create a partition and agreed to the default size.  It asked to install a 3rd party software (I think for flash/adobe)   and I agreed.  All looked good until the very end. 
Then it stopped.  I Googled in Ubuntu the issue and tried to cancel install but rebooted in the end.

Now,  I get a choice in the beginning between win 7 and Ubuntu.  However my arrow down is broken (I know,  I know,  I already ordered a new keyboard for laptop) Regardless,  I cannot scroll down to win 7, and I by default get into the broken Ubuntu,  which lead to a black screen and nothing else.  After I hard close down and restart I can get into the GNU Grub..

Now,  I can get into GNU GRUB w. 2.02~beta-9unbuntu1.

Dont have a win recovery  CD at hand.

Can I launch Windows from Gnu Grub? Then I can fix it!  It or least work today :)

I run win 7, 64 bit,  i7-2620M, 8 GB ram,  upgraded to ssd harddisk 500 GB,  Sony VAIO,  VPCSB28gg,

Comment: Or if I can set win 7 as default start program,  it could help too.

Answer (score 0):

Especially if you've got an EFI BIOS, the BIOS boot menu may let you boot straight into Windows, bypassing GRUB. Give it a try. The key to hit is BIOS-specific, ESC, F11, and F12 are all reasonably common. There may be a prompt telling you—but it could flash by pretty quick.

Does the page down button work? Or end? Then you could get to the bottom of the list, and go back up. I'd also try h/j/k/l to see if they scroll—not sure. Might be able to press a number, too.

Alternatively, you could pull up the grub command prompt (<kbd>c</kbd>) and booting Windows should be something like (type all three of these):

```
insmod chain
insmod ntfs
set root='(hd0,1)'
chainloader +1
```

That's presuming Windows is on your first partition. `hd0` is the first disk, the `,0` is the first partition. `,1` is the second partition, etc. It counts from 0.

See https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/Chain_002dloading.html#Chain_002dloading

Comment: If the system is booting in UEFI style, the grub commands to boot Windows would be slightly different: `insmod chain`, `insmod fat`, `set root='(hd0,1)'` (or whatever your EFI System Partition is), then `chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi`.